# Is there a standard way for calendar data to be passed between modules in DotNetNuke?

Tags: calendar, dotnetnuke

After reading a bit on development in DotNetNuke, I would imagine you would just pass it via the specific table in the database, and write some sort of strategy class for pulling the data in the same why from the correct calendar module.

That said, is there a particular calendar module that is popular among DNN Users?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to accomplish, could you elaborate on the business goal/feature?

Comment: @Ian I've been tasked with placing project milestones on a calendar in the portal from a DNN module that retrieves that data.  I figured if the module retrieving the mile stones already had the data, that I could use it to write that data out as milestones into another plugins database, or have it make some sort of hCal/iCal event stream that could be read into the calendar when it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a particular calendar module
>   that is popular among DNN Users?

I know that both [Engage: Events](http://www.engagesoftware.com/Products/Modules/Engage_Events.aspx) and [InvenManager's Event Calendar](http://www.invenmanager.com/Modules/EventCalendar/Overview.aspx) are widely used for calendering in DNN.